# how to instantiate an object with class name in a variable?

Tags: php

I'm used to instantiate my objects with a `use`statement such as:

```php
use acme\Toto;

function tutu()
{
    $tutu = new Toto ()
}
```

in my project, I get a class name as function argument

```php
function tutu($totoName // 'acme\Toto')
{
    $tutu = new $totoName // ?
}
```

how to instantiate in this new configuration a new object from the class `acme\toto` ?

Comment: Yes…!? This is the way…

Comment: I forget the `()`but yes It was as easy as it seems. Sorry to have created a duplicate

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the `()` if you're not passing any arguments.